# Javascript Show/Hide on radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

I have 3 radiobuttons labeled 'Squat', 'Benchpress' and 'Deadlift' which each show and hide an associated dropdown menu, (I have 3 dropdown but only one is show at each time, containing different data)

Though now I've added 3 more radiobuttons, called 'Primary', 'Secondary' and 'Assistance'. Now if primary & assistance radiobutton is selected I dont wany any dropdown to be visible at all, only when Secondary is selected. And when Secondary is selected it should only be one visible as it is at the moment! I just can't seem to get it to work.

I include this fiddle so you can get a visual and see what I mean!

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm/dd" }).val()
});

//Script for hiding dropdown menus and showing the one connected
//to the right exercise based on which radiobutton is selected.
$(function() {
  $("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 1  && this.checked) {
      $("#exerVariNameS").show();
      $("#exerVariNameB").hide();
      $("#exerVariNameD").hide();
    } else if ($(this).val() == 2  && this.checked){
      $("#exerVariNameS").hide();
      $("#exerVariNameB").show();
      $("#exerVariNameD").hide();
    } else if ($(this).val() == 3  && this.checked) {
      $("#exerVariNameS").hide();
      $("#exerVariNameB").hide();
      $("#exerVariNameD").show();
    }
  });
  //Remember which radiobutton was last clicked and keeps it that way
  //after a page refresh or form post.
  $('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
    var state = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('radio_'  + this.id) );
    if (state) this.checked = state.checked;
    $(this).trigger('change');
  });        
  $(window).bind('unload', function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
      localStorage.setItem('radio_' + this.id, JSON.stringify({checked: this.checked}));
    });
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o7m0d4uu/4/

Please ask if I explained badly!

Comment: Instead of highlighting a meaningless `@` as code, why don't you do what you were asked when you saw the BIG RED WARNING when you linked to jsFiddle and add a [mcve] in your question?

Comment: Well, now when you say it. At first I just felt like it would be a duplicate that would be read anyhow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to trigger an `click` event handler to radio buttons with `name="Type"`.

Here is solution:

```
$("input[name='Type']").click(function(){
        var value=$(this).val();
        switch(value){
            case '4':
              $("input[name='Exercise']").each(function(){
                $(this).closest('div').hide();
              });
              $('#dropdown').hide();
              break;
            case '5':
              $("input[name='Exercise']").each(function(){
                  $(this).closest('div').show();
              });
              $('#dropdown').show();
              break;
            case '6':
              $("input[name='Exercise']").each(function(){
                $(this).closest('div').hide();
              });
              $('#dropdown').hide();
              break;
        }
});
```

Here is a working [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/o7m0d4uu/8/)

Comment: Thank you very much! Its wasn't exactly as I meant but I was able to solve it. However one tiny problem remained! I'd like the first 3 radiobuttons to also remember which one was latest used like the second row of 3 radiobuttons do! An so that there is always one selected and not empty when you open it the first time if that works?

https://jsfiddle.net/o7m0d4uu/15/ 

this is the updates I did. I'd hugely appreciate any help!